# Weblogic web service + SSL

Tags: web-services, ssl, weblogic, testing

i currently have a webservice deployed on a weblogic 10.3 server whit 1-way ssl enabled, the problem is that wen i test the webservice using the weblogic's test page, i get this error:

```
avax.net.ssl.SSLException: Handshake has been interrupted, can't find trusted CA certificates file trusted-ca.pem
```

but all the client applications are not having problem using the service over https (they are allready configured tho thrust the server cert), i dig on the weblogic's log and found this stack trace:

```
at com.certicom.net.ssl.HttpsClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at com.certicom.net.ssl.internal.NetworkClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
 at com.certicom.net.ssl.internal.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
 at com.certicom.net.ssl.HttpsClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at com.certicom.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
 at com.certicom.net.ssl.internal.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
```

(this is an extract of the whole stack trace) for what i see, is that the test page interally uses the certicom ssl implementation to make the requests and it is not using the weblogic's SSL configuration, so how can i get the test page working whit ssl enabled?, is there any way to get certicom ssl implementation to use the weblogic's ssl settings?

thank you for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you follow the steps described in [Testing a Secure WebLogic Web Service From Its Home Page](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webserv/security.html#1077311)?

Comment: sorry for the mark delay, yes, allready tried that and worked like i charm, is just that i did not found that page on the documentation for the 10.3 version,for the url it seems that is on the documentation for version 8.1, thanks alot